# Error en Laravel Unknown database 'laravel'

Tags: laravel

Soy nueva en Laravel, estoy probando conectarme a mi base de datos buywihtme con Laravel y a la hora de realizar el comando php artisan migrate me da el siguiente error:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\laravBuyWithMe>php artisan migrate
>   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown
>   database 'laravel' (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where
>   table_schema = laravel and table_name = migrations and table_type =
>   'BASE TABLE')

Mi archivo .env está configurado de la siguiente forma, ¿hay que hacer algo más?

'connections' => [

```
    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
        'prefix' => '',
        'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
    ],

    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('localhost', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'buywithme'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-Intente lo siguiente, desde su terminal, ubiquese en la raiz de su proyecto y desde ahí ejecute el siguiente comando de tinker `php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 1):

las db en development puedes dejarlas con cache y manternerlo como dice Franz Garcia, lo demas seria limpiar la cache de las db 
con los siguientes comandos :

```
          php artisan cache:clear

          php artisan route:cache  

          php artisan config:clear 

          php artisan view:clear
```

adicionalmente agregas un route config

```
          Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
           Artisan::call('cache:clear');
            return "Cache is cleared";
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que estas mostrando no es el contenido del archivo **.env** este corresponde al archivo **database.php**, el primer archivo que lee Laravel para la conexion es **.env** que se encuentra en el directorio raiz.

Este es un ejemplo de los datos que deben tener el archivo .env para la conexion con la base de datos:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=cursos
DB_USERNAME=adminlaravel
DB_PASSWORD=ygaxIPufzPitJfZs
```

Otra cosa que te recomiendo es:

1) Ajustar el largo de la cadena String a la hora de construir la tabla en Laravel en migrate. (debes colocar un codigo en el archivo: AppServiceProvider.php ubicado en la ruta: app/Providers.

El codigo a colocar es:

En la cabecera coloca:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema; // llama a clase Schema
```

colocar en el metodo:

```
public function boot()
{
    // limitar la longitud a 191 chars
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

2) Finalmente te recomiendo hacer una prueba de conexion usando tinker.

tipea el comando:

**php artisan tinker**

y dentro del CLI tinker tipea:

**DB::connection()->getPdo();**

Si la conexion es existosa la respuesta seria como esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En caso contrario te muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]